# where clause is not narrowing down the records to what i have specified

Tags: mysql, sql, count, where-clause, mysql-workbench

Have some tables, and am trying to add up the number of records up, but from a particular office.

SQL :

```
  SELECT  COUNT(*) AS "Number of employees" FROM staff, office
  WHERE office.office_id  =10;
```

so want the employees from office = 10. So the field should display as "Number of employees" as 3.

Instead it adds all records up and displays "9".

Office 1 has an ID of 10
office 2 has an ID of 20

Comment: SELECT  COUNT(*) AS "Number of employees" FROM staff, office 
 Does this syntax even work ....? 
2 Tables in the same from ?

Comment: What do you mean? it works, and displays "9".

Comment: You are doing a cartesian JOIN becasue you dont have an on condition.SO every row from one table is multiplied with every row from the second table.You need something like `a JOIN b ON a.id=b.id`

Comment: @Mihai that's exactly what i meant , he wrote from A , B 
and not From A inner join B On something ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be having some relation between the two tables. Something like officeId in staff table?

```
select count(*) from staff,office where office.office_id=staff.office_id and office.office_id=10;
```

The first condition is to link the tables and the second one to filter it.

Comment: Oh thank you, been racking my brain for ages, thats solved it

Comment: I would also like to mention that if you already have officeId in staff table, you can just do: select count(*) from staff where office_id=10;

Answer (score 1):

You have to connect 2 tables to get the result you want such as:

```
   SELECT  COUNT(*) AS "Number of employees" FROM staff, office
   WHERE staff.office_id = office.office_id and office.office_id  =10;
```